# Hibernate, how to create an alias on a property of a subclass

Tags: hibernate

I have the following class hierarchy/hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="Document"
       table="KP_DOCUMENT">
    ...
</class>

<subclass name="CurrentAccountDocument"
          extends="Document"
          lazy="false">
    <many-to-one name="bankAccount"
                 class="CurrentAccount"
                 column="IBAN"
                 access="field"
                 not-null="true"
                 lazy="false"
                 cascade="none"/>
</subclass>

<class name="CurrentAccount"
       table="KP_CURRENTACCOUNT">
    <id name="iban"
        column="IBAN"
        type="string"
        access="field"/>
    <property name="baseNumber"
              column="BASENR"
              type="string"
              access="property"/>
    ...
</class>
```

I need to include properties of the class *BankAccount* as restrictions in a query to select objects of the class *Document*. So I need to create an alias for the many-to-one property *bankAccount* in the class *CurrentAccountDocument*, which is a subclass of *Document*. So when I try the following:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Document.class);
criteria.createAlias("bankAccount", "bankAccount");
queryCriterion = Restrictions.eq("bankAccount.baseNumber", "35300");
criteria.add(queryCriterion);
return criteria.list();
```

... it results in the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: bankAccount of: Document
```

I can access "normal" subclass properties in other restrictions. However with createAlias() this doesn't work. How is this done correctly?

BTW, I tried the same with the JPA criteriy API like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Document> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Document.class);
Query<Document> documentRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Document.class);
Join joinBankAccount = documentRoot.join("bankAccount");
```

or alternatively

```
Join joinBankAccount = criteriaBuilder.treat(documentRoot, CurrentAccountDocument.class).join("bankAccount");
Predicate queryPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(joinBankAccount.get("baseNumber"), "4711");
criteriaQuery.select(documentRoot).where(queryPredicate);
query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return query.getResultList();
```

... which results in a similar exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: bankAccount of: Document [select generatedAlias0 from Document as generatedAlias0 inner join generatedAlias0.documentContent as generatedAlias1 inner join generatedAlias0.bankAccount as generatedAlias2 where generatedAlias2.baseNumber=:param0 order by generatedAlias1.creationTimeStamp desc]
at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:158)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720)
```

Due to other probles with the JPA API I switched back to the deprecated hibernate criteria API until JPA works correctly. So please tell me how it works with hibernate. If you have a solution with JPA it is also welcome.

Thank you Thomas

Comment: I'm using hibernate version 5.4.3

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you get is correct.
The object "Document" does not have the property bankAccount.
Super class does not have access to the member variables of sub class. Hence the exception
One solution would be to create the property in the document object.
Another would be to create a query on the sub class instead of the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree, that the exception is correct. JPA and Hibernate, both support polymorphic queries (see JSR 338: JavaTM Persistence API, Version 2.1, 3.10.15 Polymorphic Queries and [Hibernate ORM 5.4.15.Final User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-polymorphism), 15.17. Polymorphism). And this works well with restrictions like this:

```
Restrictions.eq("subClassProperty", value)
```

It just doesn't work with alias/join and also not for sub queries like this:

```
Subqueries.propertyIn("subClassProperty", criteria);
```

I found no word about that polymorphism works only for simple restrictions.

The workaround I implemented now for this problem is to define a "dummy" attribute *bankAccountAlias* and mapping for this property in the base class *Document* as follows:

```
        <many-to-one name="bankAccountAlias"
                 class="de.bayernlb.kundenportal.businessclasses.bankaccount.BankAccount"
                 access="field"
                 not-null="false"
                 lazy="false"
                 cascade="none"
                 insert="false"
                 update="false">
        <column name="ACCOUNTID"/>
        <column name="ACCOUNTIMPORTED"/>
    </many-to-one>
```

This attribute is declared private and off course unused. It is just used to formulate the query.

**But this cannot be the solution!**

I wonder if I backed a dead horse with hibernate if this isn't possible. I also get no answers on my topics in the hibernate forum and also here in stackoverflow many hibernate related topics remain unanswered.